# How do I spawn multiple bullets with rigidbodies in the same spot without them colliding

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D game and have a basic weapon which I decided to call a pistol. I want to make a shotgun next and I have all of the work done except for the fact that they are all spawned in the same place and they all collide with each other.

I've had a few ideas like trying to turn off collisions for the rigidbodies (Didn't work), applying force without a rigidbody (Didn't work). I've done one game before this which was through a tutorial so this is my first real game and I just need help. If you need more details I can always send more. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Jump into the [Physics2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html) settings and make sure that the layer you’ve set for your “bullets” is not colliding with itself.

The one you’ll want to turn off for self collision is usually the one on the end, that intersects with itself on the row and column:
[image: Physics matrix]

Comment: I don't know where to find that and @KiynL, this is how I used it in the collision function of the shotgun bullet.                                                                
 `if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
        {
          Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(gameObject.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D> 
          (), collision.gameObject.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>());
        }`  It is still colliding but I'm probably using it wrong. I'm trying to spawn 4 bullets and all 4 will spawn but 3 will be stationary until I collide with them and 1 will have a small force applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

The script you need is the following line. In this line, Unity physics renders one collider ineffective against another.

```cs
Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(collider, ignoreCollider);
```

Also, with the algorithm below, you can neutralize all colliders at the moment of the bullet shot.

```cs
[SerializeField] private GameObject bulletType;

private List<Collider2D> _tempCollides;

void ShotBullets()
{
    _tempCollides.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        // Instantiate and catch all colliders in a List
        var collider = Instantiate(bulletType, AnyPlace, AnyRotation).GetComponent<Collider2D>();
        
        _tempCollides.Add(collider);
    }
    foreach (var _collider in _tempCollides) // For Every Bullet Collider...
    {
        foreach (var _subCollider in _tempCollides) // .. Define to Ignore other Colliders..
        {
            if (_collider != _subCollider) Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(_collider, _subCollider);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just fixed collision by finding the Physics2D menu but now I need to add the force. I can use the add force code but my normal code doesn't work with the spray of the shotgun. If you could show me how to convert an angle to a vector2 that would be great. Or a different way of adding force in the direction that the object is facing. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AsherBarrett Quaternion.AngleAxis(30f, Vector3.forward) * Vector2.right

Comment: I figured it out but thank you so so much for your help I wouldn't have been able to do it without you.